# Could/Should a jCard tag be added?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

After asking the question [Parsing JSON WHOIS data from ARIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672992/parsing-json-whois-data-from-arin), I've been searching around and found a couple of similar questions on SO (such as [Parse vcard json C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278659/parse-vcard-json-c-sharp)).  Additionally, I've done some research and found that [RFC 7095](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7095) provides the definition for a `jCard`, which apparently is basically a JSON representation of a vCard.  From the RFC:

> **jCard: The JSON Format for vCard**
>
> Abstract
>
> This specification defines "jCard", a JSON format for
> vCard data. The vCard data format is a text format for representing
> and exchanging information about individuals and other entities,
> for example, telephone numbers, email addresses, structured names,
> and delivery addresses.  JSON is a lightweight, text-based,
> language-independent data interchange format commonly used in
> Internet applications.

After finding this, I thought that it might be a good idea to re-tag my question as [jcard], but that's not currently a tag, and I don't yet have the reputation on SO to create new ones.  TBH, I'm not certain it needs to be a tag or possibly just a synonym for the [vcard] tag, but my [Google-fu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu) has uncovered at least a few questions on SO that are specifically referencing this particular format, so I thought I'd open it up for discussion.

Comment: Any programmer unlucky enough to have to deal with [vcard] has to battle the weak formatting standardization.  Instead of creating little islands where nobody can find each other anymore, it is sensible to tag [vcard][json].

Comment: Excellent point, @HansPassant.  I considered that as well, but I also look at it from the standpoint of someone who is looking specifically for information on the implementation and/or use of the jCard standard (although that specific terminology is apparently not very well known).  That person may or may not try to look for the combination of tags you proposed (although that's how I've tagged my question above).  If it were possible to make a single tag a synonym of a specific combination of tags...